# What causes this OrientDB startup error?

Tags: orientdb

I just started getting this error when running Orient. Any advise what to do?

```
2015-11-10 08:09:52:003 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=489MB (heap=491MB os=52,339MB disk=978MB) [orientechnologies]
2015-11-10 08:09:52:111 INFO  Loading configuration from: /home/ubuntu/workspace/orient215/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2015-11-10 08:09:52:391 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.1.5 (build 2.1.x@r; 2015-10-29 16:54:25+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2015-11-10 08:09:52:430 INFO  Databases directory: /home/ubuntu/workspace/orient215/databases [OServer]
2015-11-10 08:09:52:484 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.32, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.getPorts(OServerNetworkListener.java:113)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.listen(OServerNetworkListener.java:305)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.<init>(OServerNetworkListener.java:79)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:334)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
```

Comment: Did you change your configuration? Could you post here the listener part?

Comment: I typo the ports in orientdb-server-config, I wrote: <listener protocol="http" socket="default" port-range="8082-802" ip-address="0.0.0.0"> That causes the crash

Answer (score 0):

Well I deleted this question quickly because I found my own answer. But on second thought if someone else makes a typo in the port specification in orientdb-server-config.xml, then they might find this post useful